# How values gets changed in the type casting from unsigned short to unsigned int

Tags: casting

*pSelectData = 4A, *(pSelectData+1) = 54

unsigned int value = *((unsigned short*)pSelectData );

Output = 21578 (in hex 0x544A).

Can someone explain me how this is happening (how the values getting converted)??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem more specifically?

Depending on endianness you get either 0x4a54, or 0x544a. That's exactly the representation of your value as it lies in the memory.

Comment: my pointer has one byte data 4A. If i type cast it to Unsigned short it fetches two byte data. In that case it should have been '4A54'. I am storing it in unsigned int and the value gets stored in 544A. why not 4A54??

Comment: @prathvi: I think you have the endianness issue here. Depending on the hardware, the order of the bytes of a short differs. What is your hardware platform anyway?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you said i got confused with endianness itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is your memory where p=pSelectedData, ps=cast to short, pint=cast to int (little endian architecture assumed):

```
[  ][4A][54][00][00][  ]
    ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
    p   p+1 p+2 p+3 p+4
    ps      ps+1    ps+2
    pint            pint+1
```

You probably wanted to do this:

```
*(unsigned short*)pSelectedData = 0x4a;
*(unsigned short*)(pSelectedData+1) = 0x54;
```

which would give you

```
[  ][4A][00][54][00][  ]
```